# Relationship between HTTPS Healthchecks and an HTTPS connection to a GCE Instance

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up [HTTPS Load Balancing (LB)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) on [Google Compute Engine (GCE)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/overview). Key components are outlined in the [Overview Diagram](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#overview).

After successfully creating a HTTP Backend Service where 1 of 1 (GCE) instance is healthy, I decided to do the same for HTTPS. I'm using the Developer Console UI to do this.

The Healtheck "wizard" provides a drop-down menu for protocol with the option HTTP and HTTPS:

[image]

The successful HTTP Heathcheck used the path `:8080/admin/healthcheck`.
Presumably the HTTPS Healtheck will use the path `:443/admin/healthcheck`. The problem is my HTTPS Healthchecks are failing. This was expected since when visiting `https://[INSTANCE_IP]:443/admin/healthcheck` in a browser, it could not connect. So I didn't expect the Healthcheck to mark the instance as healthy.

How can I connect to `https://[INSTANCE_IP]:443/admin/healthcheck` over TLS, do I merely need to upload a certificate and create a Certificate Resource in the Developer Console (I doubt it)?

I think it's a conceptual problem too.

The URL `https://[INSTANCE_IP]:443/admin/healthcheck` does exist, I think because the instance doesn't implement TLS, the Healthcheck fails.

What is the relationship between a uploading a certificate (i.e. creating Certificate Resource) and a specific GCE instance accepting HTTPS requests such that HTTPS HealthCheck pass?

Comment: While creating the path you can choose a different path, have you tried using a path to a page which do exists (e.g /page1?

Comment: The path exists, the protocol is causing the problem. So `http://[INSTANCE_IP]:8080/admin/healthcheck` renders in a browser, but `https://[INSTANCE_IP]:443/admin/healthcheck` does not . Updated OP.

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to find your answer, you can post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#overview), it is stated:

> The client SSL session terminates at the load balancer. Sessions
>   between the load balancer and the instance can either be HTTPS
>   (recommended) or HTTP. If HTTPS, each instance must have a
>   certificate.

It is the last sentence that I was trying to achieve because HTTPS Healthchecks use a HTTPS URL to check the 'health' of an individual instance:

```
https://[INSTANCE_IP]:443/admin/healthcheck
```

Since this was failing, I incorrectly assumed I needed to implement TLS on each instance for the Healthcheck to succeed. However, I do not require each instance to implement TLS (HTTPS), only the Load Balancer.

The final configuration I used involved creating a new HTTP**S** Target Proxy, which pointed to the **same** Backend Service used for the HTTP Target Proxy. In other words: 2 Target Proxies (HTTP and HTTPS), but only one Backend Service).

Since Healthchecks are employed by Backend Services, the only Healthcheck required was the (original) unsecure Healthcheck, i.e.

```
http://[INSTANCE_IP]:8080/admin/healthcheck
```

The next sentence is important to:

> The Beta release of HTTPS load balancing only supports a single SSL
>   certificate with a single load balancing service.

If the beta release only supports a single SSL certificate, I assume this certificate belongs to the LB, and therefore, on the beta at least, it's not actually possible to secure individual instances.

Comment: Hey Jack, I'm trying to set up https load balancing, and am stuck in a similar place. I'm wondering how you were able to use 2 target proxies. I tried creating a new forwarding-rules with the second one, but that didn't work. Is there any way you could show me what your deploy script looks like? Thanks.